# In which Purana the story of Madhyandina Maharshi appears?

Tags: puranas

In which purana the story of Madhyandina Maharshi appears ? Whether  both Madhyandina Maharshi and Vyaghrapada are same ?

Comment: I think Vishnu purANa

Answer (score 7):

Sage Madhyandina is one of the fifteen disciples of Sage Yajnavalkya and a sage of Vajaseni Samhita of Yajurveda. It is mentioned in [Vayu Purana, Chapter 61, Verse, 24-25](http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/vayu-mahapurana/text-with-translation/vol-i/chapter-61).

> यजूंष्यधीयन्ते यानि ब्राह्मणा येन केन च।।
>   अश्वरूपाय दत्तानि ततस्ते वाजिनोऽभवन्॥२२॥
>
> The formulas of Yajurveda that are being studied by Brāhmaṇas were handed over to Yājñavalkya having the frame of a horse and therefrom, they became Vajinas or horses.
>
> ब्रह्महत्या तु यैश्चीर्णा चरणाच्चरकाः स्मृताः।
>   वैशम्पायनशिष्यास्ते चरकाः समुदाहृताः॥२३॥
>
> And by whom the expiatory rite for the slaughter of Brāhmana was performed, they became known as Carakas. The pupils of Vaišampāyana, all those were known as Carakas.
>
> इत्येते चरकाः प्रोक्ता वाजिनस्तान्निबोधत।
>   याज्ञवल्क्यस्य शिष्यास्ते कण्ववैधेयशालिनः॥२४॥
>   माध्यन्दिन्श्च शापेयी विदिग्धश्चाप्य उद्दलः।
>   ताम्रायणश्च वात्स्यश्च तथा गालवशैषिरी।।
>   आटवी च तथा पर्णी वीरणी सापरायणः॥२५॥
>
> These are therefore, this way called Carakas and now know the Vājins, the disciples of Yājñavalkya. They were- Kaņva, Vaidheya, Salin, **Madhyandina**, Sapeyi, Vidigdha, Apya, Uddala, Tamrayana, Vatsya, Galava, Saisiri, Atavi, Parni, Virani and Saparayana.

He is also mentioned in [Shrimad Bhagavatam, Canto 12, Chapter 6, Verse 74](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/6/74).

> yajurbhir akaroc chākhā
>    daśa pañca śatair vibhuḥ
>   jagṛhur vājasanyas tāḥ
>    kāṇva-mādhyandinādayaḥ
>
> From these countless hundreds of mantras of the Yajur Veda, the powerful sage compiled fifteen new branches of Vedic literature. These became known as the Vājasaneyi-saṁhitā because they were produced from the hairs of the horse’s mane, and they were accepted in disciplic succession by the followers of Kāṇva, Mādhyandina and other ṛṣis.

Comment: Nice find. I belong to Madhyandina shakha and very much eager to know his life story and life events.Hope that we will get it  in detail somewhere.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks. Yes, we can find more details about him.